# How to read results of 4 dimensional array in C# from tensorflow model output with image object detection

Tags: c#, tensorflow, azure-functions, object-detection

I'm trying to process an image in C# with a pre-trained tensorflow model exported from Azure Custom Vision utilizing Object Detection. How do I parse the results of the graph, which come back as a 4 dimensional array. I am looking to get tag, prediction %, and bounding box.

I have been working with tensorflow for a few weeks now so this is all pretty new to me. I have had my code working with a similar model exported from Azure Custom Vision, but utilizing Image Classification and the results were much easier to read. Now switching to a hopefully more accurate model I'm unsure how to read the results. I've been able to parse results into the 4 dimensional array, but can't make sense of it after that. I was able to verify the the model output node using tensorboard and it is a DT_FLOAT.

I am using the TensowflowSharp library at version 1.12.0

Here is an example I have been somewhat following, but I think the model used in this example was trained differently than the one provided by Azure. Which yields different results to read from the graph. I get undefined when trying the same fetch operations in the example from the link below. This is also confirmed by using graph.getEnumeration() on both my model and the model from the example.
[C# Tensorflow Object Detection Example](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/tree/master/Examples/ExampleObjectDetection)

Model and Label (tag) declarations:

```
private static readonly byte[] model = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("./Assets/model.pb"));
private static readonly string[] labels = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine("./Assets/labels.txt"));
```

Input param for image:

```
[Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
```

Processing:

```
using (var graph = new TFGraph()) {                          
     graph.Import(new TFBuffer(model));


     using (var session = new TFSession(graph)) {                                
          var tensor = TensorFlowHelper.CreateTensorFromImageFile(input);
          var runner = session.GetRunner();
          runner.AddInput(graph["Placeholder"][0], tensor)
                .Fetch(graph["model_outputs"][0]);
          var output = runner.Run();
          var result = output[0];
          var probabilities = ((float[][][][])result.GetValue(jagged: true))[0];
          Console.WriteLine(probabilities);
      }
}
```

TensorFlowHelper.CreateTensorFromImageFile:

```
var tensor = TFTensor.CreateString(contents);
TFOutput input, output;
// Construct a graph to normalize the image
using (var graph = ConstructGraphToNormalizeImage(out input, out output, destinationDataType)) {
// Execute that graph to normalize this one image
    using (var session = new TFSession(graph)) {
        var normalized = session.Run(
               inputs: new[] { input },
               inputValues: new[] { tensor },                                            
               outputs: new[] { output });
        return normalized[0];
    }
 }
```

ConstructGraphToNormalizeImage:

```
const int W = 224;
const int H = 224;
const float Mean = 117;
const float Scale = 1;

var graph = new TFGraph();
input = graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.String);
output = graph.Cast(graph.Div(
            x: graph.Sub(
              x: graph.ResizeBilinear(
                images: graph.ExpandDims(
                      input: graph.Cast(
                          graph.DecodeJpeg(contents: input, channels: 3), DstT: TFDataType.Float),
                      dim: graph.Const(0, "make_batch")),
                size: graph.Const(new int[] { W, H }, "size")),
              y: graph.Const(Mean, "mean")),
            y: graph.Const(Scale, "scale")), destinationDataType);

return graph;
```

I would expect to be able to parse out similar results to Azure's prediction API endpoint. Similar to results found in their documentation.
[Microsoft Custom Vision Image Prediction API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/csharp-tutorial-od#use-the-prediction-endpoint)

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I did not. I had an open request with Microsoft for a month or so and they steered me towards trying to use ML.Net in a function instead. I am currently working towards using python with tensorflow instead.